# Having problems with my bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for number in $@
do

echo $number | grep -q "[^a-z]" >> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
     echo "Sorry, '$number' is not a number"

else

    sum=$((sum + number))
    echo "$sum"

fi

done
```

My assignment requires that if I type `add2 4 -3 12 9` it would output

> 22

but mine outputs:

> 4 1 3 22

And if I type `add2 4 -3 twelve nine` it would output:

> Sorry, 'twelve' is not a number

but mine outputs

> 4
>   1
>   Sorry, 'twelve' is not a number
>   Sorry, 'nine' is not a number

My assignment requires `echo $number | grep -q "[^a-z]" >> /dev/null` as it wants me to redirect the output to `/dev/null`, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are printing `$sum` after each number that is processed, whereas your assignment is to print it only after the last number. So you need to move the `echo "$sum"` part (which prints `$sum`) after the loop.

In other words, you need to change this:

```
    echo "$sum"

fi

done
```

to this:

```
fi

done

echo "$sum"
```

---

> my assignment requires echo $number | grep -q "[^a-z]" >> /dev/null as it wants me to redirect the output to /dev/null, […]

That's a bit redundant. `grep -q` doesn't print anything to standard output, so there's no reason to redirect its standard output. (And anyway, this isn't a good way to detect a valid number. This approach will accept `$number` as a valid number if it contains even one character that's not a lowercase letter. For example, it would accept `ab%AB` as a valid number.)

---

**Edited to add:** O.K., so how *can* you detect a valid number? This is surprisingly tricky.

It's possible to do it by reaching your own decision about what a valid number should look like, and then crafting `grep`-commands or similar that detect numbers in this form; for example, you might write any of these:

> - `grep -q $'^-[1-9][0-9]*$\n^0$\n^[1-9][0-9]*$ <<< "$number"`
> - `grep -q '^-[1-9][0-9]*$' <<< "$number" \
>      || grep -q '^[1-9][0-9]*$' <<< "$number" \
>      || grep -q '^0$' <<< "$number"`
> - `[[ "$number" = 0 ]] || [[ "$number" =~ ^-?[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]`

but I think it's better to "cheat", by asking Bash whether it recognizes the number, and whether it agrees that the number is input in the normal way:

```
[[ "$number." = "$(printf %d "$number" 2>/dev/null && echo .)" ]]
```

Incidentally, note that with any of these approaches, there's no reason to examine `$?` explicitly. The whole point of `if` is that it runs a command and examines its exit-status. Any Bash snippet of this form:

```
foo
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    bar
else
    baz
fi
```

can also be written in this form:

```
if ! foo ; then
    bar
else
    baz
fi
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I did't notice that! thanks so much

Comment: Yea, I probably should of added the ignore case

Comment: @FiendBusa: Ignoring case would help slightly, but it would *still* accept `ab%AB` as a valid number.

Comment: ah I see, how would I avoid that?